# Duas respostas do mesmo autor na mesma pergunta

Tags: debate, respostas

Pesquisei alguns tópicos aqui no Meta e não encontrei algo que se encaixasse neste caso: qual a recomendação quando o usuário responde a uma pergunta e esta resposta ganha votos negativos e, em seguida, o mesmo usuário posta outra resposta um pouco diferente, evitando o "erro" da primeira resposta?

Me parece que ele evitou editar a primeira resposta por ter *downvotes*. O que fazer nestes casos? Solicitar o autor a excluir a segunda resposta? Sinalizar?

Comment: Acho que é melhor sinalizar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Esse tipo de atitude é contra-produtivo para o autor das respostas. Ter uma única resposta com score neutro é melhor do que ter uma resposta com score negativo e outra com score positivo, mesmo que o score de ambas se cancele (e mesmo que o total de pontos obtido seja positivo!).

A presença de uma publicação com score negativo conta para a suspensão temporária do usuário<sup>1</sup>, mesmo que a publicação seja deletada pelo autor. A prática de respostas "duplicadas" pode levar a votos negativos vindos de quem perceber essa atitude. Finalmente, pelo menos uma das duas respostas será inevitavelmente sinalizada para atenção dos moderadores.

Ainda assim, eu assumiria um erro honesto por parte do autor - pelo menos na primeira ocorrência de resposta duplicada.

O que eu faria:

- deixaria comentário na resposta alertando ao autor sobre isso;
- julgaria a resposta por seus méritos. Se for uma boa resposta, dou voto positivo. Se for uma má resposta, dou voto negativo.
- sinalizaria uma das respostas como tendo a necessidade de avaliação pelos moderadores, indicando o link da outra resposta com a qual ela se parece.

<sup>1</sup> Obviamente usuários com publicações bem recebidas, e que só recebem votos negativos uma vez a cada lua azul, não precisam se preocupar com isso. Em toda a rede as suspensões são em geral aplicadas a novatos que não entendem como o Stack Exchange funciona e insistem em erros.

Comment: Legal cara! Deu uma dissipada na dúvida. Acho que era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 14):

É raro uma mesma pessoa postar duas ou mais respostas a uma mesma pergunta. Situações em que isso ocorre de forma legítima normalmente são:

- Quando as duas respostas utilizam abordagens e técnicas completamente diferentes uma da outra.
- A primeira resposta é feita e então após alguns debates em comentários com o autor da pergunta ou com terceiros, a resposta resta invalidada e uma segunda resposta faz-se necessária. A causa disso pode ser uma pergunta-camaleão (a pergunta mudou significativamente com o tempo e a resposta ficou obsoleta) ou pode ser que o autor da resposta não havia entendido direito a pergunta e então tenta postar uma nova resposta.

É até possível editar a resposta de uma pergunta para torná-la outra coisa. Mas assim como perguntas-camaleão são ruins, respostas-camaleão também são. Então, nesse caso postar uma nova resposta pode ser uma boa saída.

É possível também colocar o conteúdo das duas respostas numa só, abordando a situação por várias óticas diferentes, mas isso daí pode deixar a resposta com cara de um frankenstein.

Por outro lado, um caso onde claramente **não** deveriam ser duas respostas é quando uma complementa a outra. Se uma resposta sua precisa de algum tipo de complemento, o melhor é então editá-la.

Comment: Realmente é raro. Em todo esse tempo acho que já me deparei com isso no máximo umas 2 vezes. No caso fiz o que achei certo: indaguei o autor o porquê de 2 respostas e ele excluiu uma delas. Mas geralmente isso acontece mesmo com novatos que pensam que é um fórum.

Comment: @dvd No caso de novatos, é por não entender como o site funciona e postar uma nova resposta ao invés de editar a antiga ou postar comentários como se fossem respostas. De forma que (eu acho) legítima, já fiz isso algumas vezes ([exemplo 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185708/132), [exemplo 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184671/132), [exemplo 3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146145/132), [exemplo 4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129718/132), [exemplo 5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97940/132), [exemplo 6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94028/132)).

Comment: @dvd E teve um caso que eu até dei 3 respostas para a mesma pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52816/132

Comment: Ah, legal. Seria uma complementando a outra?

Comment: @dvd Não. Uma complementando a outra é sinal de que deveriam ser uma resposta só.

Comment: Acho que aplicar 2 respostas é melhor do que criar uma resposta extensa.
Quando tenho abordagens diferentes geralmente eu já inicio a pergunta dizendo que há abordagens diferentes e separo a resposta por tópicos, apesar de que já me criticaram por isso.

Comment: Tenho dado duas respostas nos casos onde a primeira resolve diretamente o problema inicial, muitas vezes de forma genérica, em alto nível. Caso o usuário em dúvida não entenda, posto um exemplo de código adequado ao código de exemplo do solicitante como segunda resposta. Ao meu ver, ambas atendem a tipos de usuários diferentes. Aqueles bons entendedores inicialmente, e aqueles que buscam código pronto na segunda.